# How to do a preg-match across two columns in a row?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a working bit of code that gets a bunch of material from a MySQL table, searches for a pattern, and then orders and prints the results. So far, so good.

But now I need to do something similar across two fields in the result. So the code below searches for the pattern in the "essay" column, but I need it to find matches in the "essay" column OR the "definitions" column. If either one is a hit, I want the code to add the row to the $matches and proceed from there. (In other words, I want it to treat "essay" and "definitions" together, rather than just "essay," as the code below does.)

I tried a few ways that I thought might signify "or" in this way, but nothing worked. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
// create empty array

$query = "SELECT shortword,word,essay,definitions FROM lexicon;";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die("Query failed : " . mysql_error());
$num_results = mysql_num_rows($result);

$results = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < $num_results; $i++) {
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (preg_match_all("/(\<i\>U\<\/i\>|U) $episodenav\.[0-9]{1,4}\D/", $row["essay"], $matches)) {
        foreach ($matches[0] as $match) {
            $match = ltrim(strip_tags($match), "U ");
            // array pseudo key is the float value of $match
            // add '_key' member for usort()
            $row['_key'] = floatval($match);
            $results[] = $row;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try like this ?

```
$newtext=   $row["essay"]." ".$row["essay"]

if (preg_match_all("/(\<i\>U\<\/i\>|U) $episodenav\.[0-9]{1,4}\D/", $newText, $matches)) {
```